# Is a service running in a docker network secure from outside connection, even from localhost?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**Question:**
Can anybody with access to the host machine connect to a Docker network, or are services running within a docker network only visible to other services running in a Docker network assuming the ports are not exposed?

**Background:**
I currently have a web application with a postgresql database backend where both components are being run through docker on the same machine, and only the web app is exposing ports on the host machine. The web-app has no trouble connecting to the db as they are in the same docker network. I was considering removing the password from my database user so that I don't have to store the password on the host and pass it into the web-app container as a secret. Before I do that I want to ascertain how secure the docker network is.

Here is a sample of my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

    database:
        image: postgres:9.5
        restart: always
        volumes:
              #preserves the database between containers
            - /var/lib/my-web-app/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data                

    web-app:
        image: my-web-app
        depends_on:
            - database
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "8443:8443"
        restart: always
        secrets:
            - source: DB_USER_PASSWORD

secrets:
  DB_USER_PASSWORD:
    file: /secrets/DB_USER_PASSWORD
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a native Linux host, anyone who has or can find the container-private IP address can directly contact the container.  (Unprivileged prodding around with `ifconfig` can give you some hints that it's there.)  On non-Linux there's typically a hidden Linux VM, and if you can get a shell in that, the same trick works.  And of course if you can run any `docker` command then you can `docker exec` a shell in the container.

Docker's network-level protection isn't strong enough to be the only thing securing your database.  Using standard username-and-password credentials is still required.

(Note that the `docker exec` path is especially powerful: since the unencrypted secrets are ultimately written into a path in the container, being able to run `docker exec` means you can easily extract them.  Restricting `docker` access to root only is also good security practice.)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to confirm, and yes I am making sure docker exec needs sudo to run.